# Where can I find a collection of maximum range at maximum payload values for all aircraft types?

Tags: icao, datasets, range, payload

The scope of my Master Thesis is the development of an assignment algorithm of aircraft types to routes with a given distance. As part of violation checks I'm validating the possible range of the AC type against the route distances.

As defined per payload-range diagram the max range of an aircraft type is not a static value but depends on the amount of payload desired. For a more realistic approach I'm looking for values of the max range at maximum payload of every aircraft type defined in ICAO Doc 8643.

However this value is not very easy to find out. Does anyone have an idea where to find a list of all (or at least all major aircraft types) max ranges at max payload of all aircraft types given in ICAO Doc 8643 grouped by the ICAO Designators (e.g. A332, B773, etc.)

Comment: The range is not only depending on aircraft type and payload but on many more variables like winds, temperature, cruise speed, installed engine model, number of installed fuel tanks etc. etc.

Comment: I doubt such a list exists. You would likely have to compile the list from each PIM.   Creating new datasets that didn't exist before is a wonderful output from Master Theses.

Comment: I always enjoy looking at sales material for new aircraft... They usually have several range rings. As any pilot knows... It can be quite dependent on weather.

Comment: One ICAO designator can indicate multiple aircraft types with different MTOW and engines. Take for example the A320 and A320neo, or Boeing 767-300 and 767-300ER (with or without winglets). Instead of looking for every aircraft type, I would suggest to take just a few aircraft types (specify them more detailed) and try to get information for them. [This website](http://www.aircraftmonitor.com/payload-range-passenger.html) may help you, but I didn't check how reliable the numbers are.

Comment: Hello together! Thx very much for the many replies. I'll have to validate the different recommended sources. Overall I know about the comments of @DeltaLima. The purpose is to get a good average of all these variants of the single AC types

Comment: @FelixWindisch If I were you, I wouldn't go for the `average of all these variants` but instead pick a single variant and explicitly state which one you took. You could for example take the most common variety or the one that has an average performance. That way you avoid fuzziness in your work and increase the value of the results.

Comment: @DeltaLima never thanked you for the edit, was still new and wasn't sure I can post direct links to documents, so thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the DVB Bank report "[An Overview of Commercial Jet Aircraft 2013 - 2014](https://www.dvbbank.com/~/media/files/d/dvb-bank-corp/documents/dvb-aviation-finance-commerical-aircraft-booklet-2013.pdf)," contains the information you are looking for.

It contains a type description, performance data, world fleet data and engines for many aircraft types, as well as payload-range diagrams for each aircraft category.

Comment: This looks promising. Thx for the tip!

Comment: Interesting document anyway, I guess the diagrams could be reused as an additional reference in many answers. Good find!